# Where in the world does the Skyrim trailer take place?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In the [Elder Scrolls V Skyrim: Official Gameplay Trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PjqsYzBrP-M), the character fights a dragon at the edge of a cliff. What is this location? Is it a real location in the game?

Comment: There are several similar cliffs in the game, I'm not sure there's enough detail in the video to tell where exactly this is.

Answer (score 7):

Around 2:20 in the trailer, when the camera starts flying, you can see Bleak Falls Barrow. The mountain to the right is most likely the Throat of the World. So the fighting spot should be south/south east of Bleak Falls Barrow.

Comment: Bleak Falls Barrow :) But I agree with the rest ;-)

Comment: It seems Im not the first one getting that wrong, if you try google black falls barrow ;) TY

Comment: Now dear, other people's stupidity is no excuse for your own ;-) Heh

Answer (score 1):

It is the Throat of the World -- the highest place in the game.

Comment: I don't believe this is true; You can clearly see trees and shrubs near the edge of the cliff, and even higher mountains in the distance.

Answer (score 0):

I looked for this in game, and the trailer location doesn't exist. I'm right where it should be, but I'm flying and there is no cliff.

This location does not exist in game.

Comment: Hi Marc. welcome to gaming.stackexchange.com . If you wish for people to look at your screenshots, please either embed them in your post or link to where they are available. Just asking people to "look at my screens" isn't really answering the question

Comment: Sorry I was thinking you could go to steam and look at my steam name. Idk how Embed them on here. But over all my answer is that the location does not exist

Answer (score -1):

At 2:13, you can see Bleak Falls Barrow. next to it is the Throat of the World. The location is probally southwest of Bleak Falls.